# Disallow ssh on domain names

Tags: ssh

There are certain domains pointing to my server.

```
# example.com
example.com goes to 20.20.20.20
```

I want to deny ssh access using this domain names. I want my server to only accept ssh connections on `20.20.20.20`. How can I configure this?

#### What I have tried

```
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UseDNS no
```

Example:

If user1 connects to 20.20.20.20 then it should show the login, otherwise it should just drop all connections.

I am on a Debian Distribution.

Comment: Your question really doesn't make it sound as though you are a professional system administrator. [sf] only deals with questions from professionals and they expect a certain level of knowledge and understanding from the people who ask there. Are you _sure_ you want this moved there? Also, please don't ask two questions in a single post. I have removed your second question, please ask it separately.

Comment: Sshd doesn't know if the connection targeted a name or an IP

Comment: No, if that's the case. Leave my question here.

Comment: The `UseDNS` option on the server makes a _reverse DNS_ lookup of the IP address of the connecting client and then a _forward DNS_ lookup for the resulting name and looks if the result is the IP again. In a time where every dial-up connection has a valid DNS entry and cloud instances with proper DNS records are used for SSH scans, this option is not very helpful anymore.

Answer (score 8):

You can't.  What you ask is impossible in SSH.

It's possible in HTTP, because HTTP/1.1 sends a `Host` header to tell the server which (virtual) host to connect to.  SSH sends no such field.  You can see this using the Wireshark network protocol dissector.

If it was possible to do this, obviously it wouldn't provide any additional security.

Please briefly describe *why* you are trying to perform a given task (I think StackExchange advises this).  I wouldn't say you tend to get nasty pile-ons without constructive explanations here.  (Um.  In light of that: if you're looking at SSH hardening in general, a common & robust solution is to deny password logins and instead use an SSH key stored on your computer).